# php oauth pecl or create own class

Tags: php, oauth, pecl

i m developing appliction of contact grabber.i use both PHP PECL ofr oauth and my class.both work well but php PECL has very poor documentation.
so which i have to used for my application?

Comment: I don't have experience in the field but surely there are other oAuth classes for PHP that are better documented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Oauth-PHP](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/) is a consumer and server library for PHP I used in my project. Learning the basic concepts of OAuth may help; see http://hueniverse.com/oauth/guide/workflow/ . You also have client-side examples in that application. But I got to admit, while the code is straightforward, the accompanying explanations are sparse (hence my advice on learning the basic concepts).

Comment: i know all the concept of oauth .Also implemented contact grabber in gmail , yahoo ,hotmail ,linkedin using oauth core and php PECL  .but confused with which to finalize?

Comment: 'oauth core' you mean the reference implementation from oauth.net?  Do download oauth-php and see the included client examples (actual code for fetching stuff from Google, Twitter). You can quickly decide if the code is simple and adaptable to your needs. Do check out the activity of the community (where can you go if the package itself gives you trouble) and production deployments (who trusts the code for their applications) for choosing a particular package.

Comment: my friend  , i refere it all. i dont know which is best in performance or adaptibility ?

Comment: Performance: upgrade your infrastructure when it cannot cope. Have n web servers that refer to the same DB. Do you insist on squeezing the maximum from a shared host forever? As for adaptability, a "protected access" is a simple HTTP request. What more adaptability do you need? If you have atleast one option that meets your current needs, go choose one and **do it anyway**. You can move to another library later without much fuss.

Comment: Uh, you **accept** answers first - its the tick mark under the vote button :-) You are ALWAYS allowed to ask, accept answers and even answer questions. In fact, do accept satisfactory answers. Not accepting answers is a common newb mistake more experienced people quickly point out.